# Pass object from DB to next page after listbox selection

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a listbox populated by products stored in an SQLite DB. The listbox is populated like so:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string navigatedFrom;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        navigatedFrom = (string)e.Parameter;

        if (navigatedFrom == "main")
        {
            var products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(data.GetProducts().ToList());

            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                ListBox.Items.Add("Product Name: " + product.ProductName + " Price: " + product.Price + " Quantity: " + product.Quantity);
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

and the listbox selection is handled like this:

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var product = ListBox.SelectedItem as Product;

        if (product != null)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(DetailsPage), product.Id);
        }

        ListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

When a product is selected from the listbox the app should navigate to the details page which shows all of the details from the selected product object. My problem occurs when I select a product from the list, the product object is always null. How can I make sure the product object is populated in the correct format with the correct information?

Comment: So when you populate the listbox you're just chucking in a bunch of strings, then when you want to see what is selected you're suddenly expecting a object of type `Product` to magically appear?

Comment: Okay I see the dumb mistake but I need the list to output the productName, productPrice and productQuantity. Is it possible to display that information while being able to access the object that has been selected?

Comment: you can go into your class and do an override on the `ToString()` method and out put whatever you want - that's a quick way to get it working

Comment: This is the part I was missing, thank you very much for the help, it's much appreciated!

Comment: no problem, click the tick if you're happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
foreach (var product in products)
{
    ListBox.Items.Add("Product Name: " + product.ProductName + " Price: " + product.Price + " Quantity: " + product.Quantity);
}
```

to

```
foreach (var product in products)
{
    ListBox.Items.Add(product);
}
```

example Product class:

```
    public class Product
    {
        public string ProductName { get; private set; }
        public string Price { get; private set; }
        public string Quantity { get; private set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Product Name: {this.ProductName} Price: {this.Price} Quantity: {this.Quantity}";
        }

    }
```